# Use UMTS Stick as a "dial in" modem - no dataplan required

Tags: debian, modem, getty, telephony, huawei

I would like to create an on demand very low bandwidth data connection between two computers.

For this I am planing to have a proxy and a client which both have a UMTS modem (e.g. Huawei e169). The simcard inside the proxy's UMTS stick has the ability to call the clients number for free!

When I want access to the client from the proxy, I want to do the following:

```
Proxy:        Calls client -> 
Client:       Picks up ->
Proxy/Client: Use some kind of protocol to establish an internet connection
```

When I want access from the client to the proxy I want to do the following:

```
Client:       Calls proxy -> 
Proxy:        Declines the call ->
Proxy:        Calls client back ->
Client:       Picks up ->
Proxy/Client: Use some kind of protocol to establish an internet connection
              using DTMF or something like it.
```

Now to the questions:

- Is it possible to place/receive calls in Linux (Debian)?
- Is this possible with the Huawei E169? I chose it as it seemed to have very good Linux support but am able to switch.
- Is it possible to use `pppd` for this?
- Else, is it possible to redirect the phone output to something like Python and work with it from there? Is this where I could use `mgetty`?

Comment: AFAIR mobile operators can tell if a connection is used for data transfer...

Comment: At least the data calls should be enabled for both SIMs and this is not the same as a voice call

Comment: I don't need to achive high bandwidth. In the worst case I would write an application which uses text to speech and speech to text to transfer the 1s and 0s ;) First step is I want to make and receive calls. What software would I use?